# How to send params via this.props.navigation.openDrawer() in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm new in react native. i want to send params via this.props.navigation.openDrawer() function in react native. this is my code: but, doesn't work.

```
refreshSettingView() {
    console.log('refresh data setting')
  }

render() {
return(
     <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
         this.props.navigation.openDrawer(this.refreshSettingView.bind(this))
        }
    }>
         <Text>Button Open</Text
     </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to send params to ` openDrawer()` ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: i wanna refresh the page when the drawer close then the same page call the function refreshSettingView() @SteveNosse

Comment: Ok.. let me try a solution

Answer (score 1):

In your drawer component, try:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (props) => {
    if(!props.navigation.state.isDrawerOpen){
         // Refresh the page here 
    }
}
```

The `componentWillReceiveProps` method will be called every time the props passed to the props passed change. A complete reference about `componentWillReceiveProps` can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Let me know if it works!
Thanks.

Comment: doesnt work, when closeDawer the page still can not refresh.

Comment: the page file and the drawer file is different. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094557/how-to-reload-data-view-component-after-close-drawer-in-react-native

Comment: May be you can create a global function that refresh the page and then call it here